# How to zip contents of but not the folder

Tags: python, file, directory, zip, pathlib

I am working with the following folder structure:

```
.
+-- temp
|   +-- sample1.csv
|   +-- sample2.csv
+-- zips
|   +-- zip1.zip
|   +-- zip2.zip
+-- main.py
```

I want to zip the contents of the `temp` folder into a zip file, but I do not want to include the folder. I have tried the following (expecting to compress only the files):

```
import pathlib
import zipfile

origin = pathlib.Path('.') / 'temp'
destination = pathlib.Path('.') / 'zips' / 'zip3.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(destination, mode='w') as zipfile_:
    for content in origin.iterdir():
        zipfile_.write(content)
```

I also tried using `shutil.make_archive()`, but it rendered the same result, the only diference being that the directory was simply named `"."`.

---

EDIT: Thank you [CookieReaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12829979/cookiereaver) and [metatoaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904896/metatoaster) (I believe) for pointing out that `ZipFile.write()` method has an argument called `arcname` that will name the file ([ZipFile.write() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)).

Here is my original question with the fix applied:

```
import pathlib
import zipfile

origin = pathlib.Path('.') / 'temp'
destination = pathlib.Path('.') / 'zips' / 'zip3.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(destination, mode='w') as zipfile_:
    for content in origin.iterdir():
        zipfile_.write(content, content.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import zipfile
import os

orig = r"path_to_origin_dir"
dest = r"path_to_destination_dir"

zip_name = "zip3.zip"
target_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(dest, zip_name), 'w')

for dp, dn, fn in os.walk(orig):

    for filename in fn:
        if filename.endswith('csv'):
            target_zip.write(os.path.join(dp, filename), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dp, filename), orig))

target_zip.close()
```

Is this what you're aiming for?